# Can we fetch the flutter IconData with flutter Icon name?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

##### Abstract :

I would like to use dynamic icons with custom widget. Inorder to use dynamic icons I need Icon data number. Is there there any each way to get the icon data ?

##### Example :

```
Icon Name - Icon(Icons.abc)
```

##### Needed :

```
IconData(0xf04b6, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using a name but You can extract icon data directly from the icon you mentioned.

```
Icons.abc.codePoint

Icons.abc.fontFamily
```